# EST and EDT time info

Tags: c#

I need to know the TimeZoneinfo which takes care of EST and EDT both i.e. if EST time is applicable then it should give me EST time and when EDT is applicable then I should get EDT time.

Can following method be used in C#?

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Eastern Standard Time")

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This [Time Zone Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397783.aspx) might give you some useful background.  The documentation for [ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396328.aspx) says

> When performing the conversion, the
>   ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId method
>   applies any adjustment rules in effect
>   in the destinationTimeZoneId time
>   zone.

Adjustment rules are what define Daylight Time so yes, using "Eastern Standard Time" as an ID will get you Eastern Daylight Time when it applies.

If you want to do several conversions, the [FindSystemTimeZoneById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx) method can be used to retrieve a TimeZoneInfo object.  The documentation for FindSystemTimeZoneById also explains where in the registry these IDs can be found.

Of course both ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId and FindSystemTimeZoneById can only work if the time zone id is in the registry (but Eastern Standard Time should be there!).  Also, the adjsutment rules can change when governments decree so the adjustment rules that apply may depend on how up to date the definition of a time zone on your system is.